# How can i query table within table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i make a query that takes everything from one table then joins another table and put the values from the second table in a certain column in the result

What i am asking can be better explained:

```
clients:
id | name      | age | ...
---------------------
15 | something | 30  |
17 | somethiaa | 30  |
13 | ggggthing | 30  |

clients_meta:
id | client_id | meta_key  | meta_value |
-----------------------------------------
1  | 15        | location  | NY         |
2  | 15        | height    | 195        |
3  | 15        | job       | student    |
4  | 13        | location  | TN         |
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT
`clients`.*,
`clients_meta`.*

FROM `clients`

JOIN clients_meta ON ( clients_meta.client_id = clients.id )

WHERE
`clients_age` = '30'
```

how can instead of a ugly table like that:

```
15 | something | 30  | 1  | 15        | location  | NY         |
15 | something | 30  | 2  | 15        | height    | 195        |
15 | something | 30  | 3  | 15        | job       | student    |
```

change it to something like:

```
15 | something | 30  | 1  | 15        | location  | NY         |
                     | 2  | 15        | height    | 195        |
                     | 3  | 15        | job       | student    |
```

thanks

Comment: That's just how MySQL (and most other RDBMses) work. Get used to it, there's nothing ugly about it.

Comment: So how can i do a more advanced queries like adding even more data from a 3rd table ?

Comment: You can make a complex query to fix this, but rather I would just query the flattened data and prettify it only when you need to output it.

Comment: You can just add more joins to your query to get even more data. I totally agree with Gordon, the first version looks way better to me too.

Comment: i see well. i will keep playing with it thanks.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that no one has asked -- but if you are trying to make it look prettier, why are you doing everything in SQL? Use SQL to store the data, and use something else to query, format, display, etc. That's what most of the world does in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable to check whether the last id is equal to the current id, and in that case output null or '' instead.

```
select
  case when c.ClientId <> @clientid then c.Name else '' end as ClientName,
  case when c.ClientId <> @clientid then @ClientId := c.ClientId else '' end as ClientId,
  p.ContactId,
  p.Name as ContactName
from
  Clients c
  inner join Contacts p on p.ClientId = c.Clientid
  , (select @clientid := -1) x
order by
  c.ClientId, p.ContactId
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/658e4c/6

Note, this is a bit hacky. I deliberately made ClientId the second field, so I could change and return the clientId variable in the same field. In other, more elaborate cases, you may have to do that in a separate field. But to eliminate that placeholder field from the result, you'll have to embed the whole query in a subselect, and define the wanted fields in the right order on the top level query.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose one value in clients_meta.meta_key to always be first like 'location'. Then you can sort by clients.id, then by whether or not meta_key = 'location'. Any rows where meta_key != 'location', you can hide, like this:

```
select 
    case when clients_meta.meta_key = 'location' 
        then clients.id else '' end as id
    , case when clients_meta.meta_key = 'location' 
        then clients.name else '' end as name
    , case when clients_meta.meta_key = 'location' 
        then clients.age else '' end as age
    , clients_meta.* 
    from clients join clients_meta on (clients_meta.client_id = clients.id) 
    where clients.age = '30' 
    order by clients.id, clients_meta.meta_key = 'location' desc;
```

You will obtain the results that you wanted:

```
+------+-----------+------+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| id   | name      | age  | id | client_id | meta_key | meta_value |
+------+-----------+------+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 13   | ggggthing | 30   |  4 |        13 | location | TN         |
| 15   | something | 30   |  1 |        15 | location | NY         |
|      |           |      |  3 |        15 | job      | student    |
|      |           |      |  2 |        15 | height   | 195        |
+------+-----------+------+----+-----------+----------+------------+
```