# LEFT JOIN show first row from first table only one time

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two:

Firest table: table1

```
id   |  text   
-------------
1       t1      
2       t2           
...
```

Second table: table2

```
id   |  idTable1 |  text2
-------------------------------
1       1           text1Table2
2       1           text2Table2
3       1           text3Table2
4       2           text4Table2
5       2           text5Table2
...
```

If i do LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.idTable1
```

the result is this:

```
id  |   text |  id | idTable1 | text2
------------------------------------------
1       t1      1   1           text1Table2
1       t1      2   1           text2Table2
1       t1      3   1           text3Table2
2       t2      4   2           text4Table2
2       t2      5   2           text5Table2
...
```

But i want the rows that are duplicated in the first table to be displayed only once like this:

```
id  |   text |  id | idTable1 | text2
------------------------------------------
1       t1      1   1           text1Table2
1       -       2   1           text2Table2
1       -       3   1           text3Table2
2       t2      4   2           text4Table2
2       -       5   2           text5Table2
...
```

**Edit:**
And this result to add in mysql view

Comment: This question, well one VERY similar was JUST asked a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833254/how-can-i-query-table-within-table

Comment: i whant all the data from join but the `t1` is show 3 time but to show only first time and after replace with `'` from the remaining rows

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do not confuse data storage and  retrieval (the preserves of MySQL) with data display (the preserve of everything else)

Comment: @Strawberry i want this because i want to bind the view result in yii mvc on `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` control and if i want to process the correct mysql data in php i need to create more query and is more complicate. is some other method? my database is not big and the query will run fast and the php data processing will need more memory and CPU to process this query. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement and a subquery to determine whether a row is the first (i.e. has the lowest `table2.id`) for a given `table2.idTable`

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS SELECT 
    t1.id id1,
    (CASE
        WHEN t2.idTable1 IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM table2 t3
            WHERE t3.idTable1 = t2.idTable1
            AND t3.id < t2.id
        ) THEN t1.text ELSE '-'
    END) text1,
    t2.id id2,    
    t2.idTable1,
    t2.text2
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.idTable1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using variables:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       if(@prevtext = text, '-', if(@prevtext := text, t1.text, t1.text)) as text,
       t2.id, t2.idTable1, t2.text2
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.idTable1 CROSS JOIN
     (select @prevtext := '') vars
ORDER BY t1.id, t1.text;
```

However, I discourage you from doing this.  A result set in SQL has the same properties as a table.  Namely, each row is independent of the other rows.  When you put data in this format, you are requiring a particular ordering of the result set, so it no longer has the properties of a SQL table.

EDIT:

I thought this was impossible to do with a subquery compatible with a view, but it may be possible given the data your query (where the t2 id is ordered):

```
SELECT t1.id,
       (case when text = (select text
                          from table2 tt2
                          where tt2.id < t2.id
                          order by tt2.id desc
                          limit 1
                         )
             then '-' else text
        end) as text
       t2.id, t2.idTable1, t2.text2
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.idTable1 
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id;
```

Comment: this is the result ....goood and now how can i add this in view, because the view not support variable?

Comment: @TotPeRo . . . You changed the question after I answered it.  You cannot do this in a view, at least not very easily.

Comment: @GordenLinoff sorry because i edit the question after...I never thought at that time it would be a response with variables..but your answered is good and i give you one vote. Can you help me with the query to create view? you say is not recommended to alter the result.. i want this result because i want to print dummy data in php page.